# Solving multilinear equations

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis

Let $N=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Suppose we are given $n$ equations, with each equation taking the form $\sum_{A\subseteq N}\left(c_A \prod_{i\in A}x_i \right) = 0$, where each $c_A$ is a real number constant. (So each equation contains at most $2^n$ terms.) An example for $n=3$ is:

$$2x_1x_2x_3 - 4x_1x_2+5x_3+2=0$$

$$7x_1x_3 - 6x_2-4=0$$

$$-x_1x_2x_3 + x_1 - 2x_2 +9 = 0$$

We want to find a solution $(x_i)_{i\in A}$ such that $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ for all $i$ (assuming we know such a solution exists).

Is there an algorithm that solves this in time bounded in $n$?

Comment: This is as hard as solving general polynomial equations.

Comment: When you say "solve", are you asking for a numerical solution, or what?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Can we possibly solve this exactly (like we can do for linear equations), or is there some reason why this is impossible?

Comment: @Alexi *Exactly*, no. With the trick in Vladimir Dotsenko's answer you can easily write a degree-5 polynomial equation in this form, by adding extra variables for $x^2, x^3, x^4$. Evil Abel foils our plans again.

Comment: In numerical practice, I would use something like Newton's method or homotopy continuation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multilinear equations are hardly easier than general equations. For instance, the multilinear equations 
 $$
\begin{cases}
x_0-x_1=0,\\
x_0x_1-x_2=0,\\
x_0x_2-x_3=0,\\
\ldots\\
x_0x_{n-1}-x_n=0
\end{cases}
 $$
simply tell you that $x_k=x_0^k$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$. Using this, it is very easy to replace any system of polynomial equations by a system of multilinear ones, so I assume that the most standard method (Gröbner bases) would be the main tool to use.